# How to set additive parameter to laravel collection map method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections

In my laravel 5.7 I try to remake a small piece of application using collection

```
$selectedSubscriptions = [1,2,3];
$siteSubscriptionsList = [];
$siteSubscriptions     = SiteSubscription
    ::getByActive(true)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
foreach ($siteSubscriptions as $next_key => $nextSiteSubscription) {
    $is_found = false;
    foreach ($selectedSubscriptions as $next_value) {
        if ($nextSiteSubscription->id == (int)$next_value) {
            $is_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    $siteSubscriptionsList[] = (object)['name' => $nextSiteSubscription->name, 'id' => $nextSiteSubscription->id, 'checked' => $is_found];
}
```

like :

```
$selectedSubscriptions = [1,2,3];
$siteSubscriptionsList     = SiteSubscription
    ::getByActive(true)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ( $item, $selectedSubscriptions ) {
        $is_found = false;
        foreach ($selectedSubscriptions as $next_value) {
            if ($item->id == (int)$next_value) {
                $is_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (object)['name' => $item->name, 'id' => $item->id, 'checked' => $is_found];

    })
    ->all();
```

But I need to set additive parameter $selectedSubscriptions into map function, as it does not work, as I see that inside os a map
function has “0” value.
How correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing data through to the `->map()` closure, you use the `use` statement (which follows the `function()` call):

```
$selectedSubscriptions = [1,2,3];
$siteSubscriptionsList = SiteSubscription
    ::getByActive(true)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) use ($selectedSubscriptions) {
        $is_found = false;
        foreach ($selectedSubscriptions as $next_value) {
            if ($item->id == (int)$next_value) {
                $is_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (object)['name' => $item->name, 'id' => $item->id, 'checked' => $is_found];

    })
    ->all();
```

The second parameter of `->map()` will always be the variable of the `$key`.

**Sidenote:** You can reduce your `foreach` check for the id with the following:

```
$is_found = collect($selectedSubscriptions)->contains($item->id);
```